# python type hints for none or something

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

consider the following snippet

```
uri_match: Optional[Match[str]] = re.match(r"https//(.+?)/(.+)", "bla bla")
```

`re.match` has type `Match` or None.

```
res = uri_match.group(1)
```

This line says that `None` has no member `group`. Which means that the type checker sees that the return may be `None` and hence raises the error.
How do we deal with these?

Comment: `if uri_match:     res = uri_match.group(1)`

Comment: thanks but is that the only way we can solve this?

Comment: or you can try to use `try: res = uri_match.group(1) except: #what you want to do to handle res == None error`

Comment: thanks but there has to be a way to deal with probable none types right?
otherwise i would have to keep doing the try or ifs throughout the whole codebase

Comment: BTW, I found your regex maybe has a bug, it should be `https://(.+?)/(.+)` ? You may miss a `:`

Answer (score 1):

The static type checker is telling you that if your `re.match` call failed to find the pattern (and so `uri_match` is `None`), the second call is going to fail too, with an exception for a missing method.

How you solve that depends on what the correct behavior of your program is. Perhaps you have some fallback value you could assign to `uri_match` (or to `res`), or you could get a different `"bla blah"` string and try the match again on it.

Or maybe a failed match makes the rest of the code meaningless, and any fallback needs to happen at some higher level of your program's logic. In that case, raising an exception is probably the right thing to do (though returning a special value like `None` could be a possible alternative).

Here's some example code that runs through a few different contingencies before giving up:

```
uri_match: Optional[Match[str]] = re.match(r"https//(.+?)/(.+)", "bla bla")

if uri_match is None:
    uri_match = re.match(r"https//(.+?)/(.+)", "foo bar")   # try another input

if uri_match is not None:
    res = uri_match.group(1)   # condition this line, so it only runs when we have a match
elif default is not None:
    res = default              # maybe there's some default result we can use?
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid input")  # if not, raise an exception

... # use res below
```

Your code probably won't do all of those things, but one or two might make sense for your program.

Comment: to me this seems odd
like a none should be just none like in other languages
in python this is pretty hectic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to in other languages. If your match wasn't found, what do you expect `uri_match.group(1)` to do? The static checker is just warning you in advance that there's a potential bug there, at runtime you'd get an `AttributeError` exception since `None` doesn't have a `group` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it by `if` or `try-except`.If you afraid to use too many `if` or `try-except` around codebase, you can use function to get result. All duplicate `if` or `try-except` will cover by function so no need to worry it.

handle by `if` code:

```
import re
def handle_by_if(s):
    uri_match = re.match(r"https://(.+?)/(.+)", s)
    if uri_match:
        return uri_match.group(1)
    print(f"handle_by_if: {s} not match anything")
    return ""

print(handle_by_if("https://stackoverflow.com/questions"))
print("-"*20)
print(handle_by_if("bla bla"))
```

result:

```
stackoverflow.com
--------------------
handle_by_if: bla bla not match anything
```

handle by `try-except` code:

```
def handle_by_try_except(s):
    uri_match = re.match(r"https://(.+?)/(.+)", s)
    try:
        return uri_match.group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        print(f"handle_by_if: {s} not match anything")
        return ""

print(handle_by_try_except("https://stackoverflow.com/questions"))
print("-"*20)
print(handle_by_try_except("bla bla"))
```

result:

```
stackoverflow.com
--------------------
handle_by_if: bla bla not match anything
```

Comment: The second solution is better, if the pattern matches most of the time, because its [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission - EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many [try](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) and `except` statements. The technique contrasts with the `LBYL` style common to many other languages such as C.